# Webview loading URL does not work for ajax requests

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

My code:

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWeb);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl("https://www.test.com");
```

This code load website and links ( `href` ) works fine, but if in website used `ajax` request , not will works and not responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library

```
dependencies {
    implementation'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0'
}
```